# Highcharts not rendering in IE 11

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using **Highcharts JS v2.2.5**. It works fine in all browser except **IE 11**. I am able see the data but, Chart is not rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have already excluded for wrong position or zero-height container? it's a common bug..

We need to know more details, can you post some code?

Have you any error evidence in browser console?

Comment: It was a container height issue.Thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using prototype.js version 1.5.1.1 then there is a possibility of getting error in console[on hover function] only in IE[All versions]. If this is the issue then it can be solved by using higher version of prototype.js