# Can I fool IE11 to operate IE10?

Tags: css, highcharts, internet-explorer-11

I have searched and searched, read and read for several days now.
I am using Highcharts/jfiddle for reporting purposes. My reports are perfect when using another browser other than IE11. According to a compatibility chart that I found IE11 has compatibility issues with what I'm using. My client uses IE11.
What I want to know.. is there something that I can do programmatically, e.g., CSS or HTML that would force IE11 to run a previous version.

Yes, I have tried compatibility mode settings.
Any help is welcome.
Regards,
Steve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forcing IE 11 to behave as IE 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588769/forcing-ie-11-to-behave-as-ie-10)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highcharts not rendering in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28559843/highcharts-not-rendering-in-ie-11)

Comment: I think the better way is to upgrade highcharts so it works in all modern browsers

Comment: In addition to the duplicate... you shouldn't actually be attempting to do this. You should be writing custom CSS rules that override HighCharts to provide compatibility. Remember to give your containers heights...

Answer (score 0):

You should try placing this at the beginning of your head tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

Officially the tag is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx), but it is worth a try to see if Internet Explorer 11 will still respect it.

Comment: I will try this, Thank you kindly.

Comment: As unpopular the decision to introduce this tag was with much of the developer community, I think Microsoft was on the right track. Instead of creating something Internet Explorer specific, Microsoft should have introduced a render date. Say you finished your site in 2003 and never cared to change anything, You could place a render tag with an iso date. Then any browser loading the page would know they should use the rendering engine that just preceded that date. If one does not exist they would use the oldest available rendering engine.

Comment: Such a feature is important to the stability of an aging knowledge base. It also allows the introduction of disruptive and breaking changes in web standards.